# How to execute a query based on the condition if a column exists?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to run the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy AS
SELECT x, y, z
FROM table1
WHERE y!=0
```

then I want to do the following:

```
if z column has a non-null entry do:
1. copy the content of z into A
2. drop z
SELECT x,A
FROM Dummy
```

What the second query essentially tries to do is that copy those rows of z into A which have no missing values.
My question is how can we write query 2 and if there is a way to merge these two queries into one for optimisation?

Any help/advice much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean (update/delete & select) in one single query?
And where column `a` comes from?

Comment: Yes, I guess. This is what I mean. Column A is created based on the condition if  z column has non-null entries.

Comment: There's no way to Update and Drop in the same query, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you aren't using column y, you can ignore it in your first query. Then, you can simplify this with a single statement:

```
SELECT 
    x, 
    A = z
FROM table1
WHERE y!=0 and z is not null
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I am sorry I did not understand the solution. I think I was not clear in my question. I am trying to create a new column 'A' which has the contents of column z only when there are non-null entries in z (i.e z column has no missing data).

Comment: @T.H. then the simplified edit should work